# Git submodules PyFlakes

Tags: git, vim, pyflakes

Hi folks I'm trying to power up my Vim, so I started to use plugins from GitHub, but after install [PyFlakes plugin](https://github.com/kevinw/pyflakes-vim) I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 82, in check
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/pyflakes/checker.py", line 176, in __init__
    self.handleChildren(tree)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/pyflakes/checker.py", line 267, in handleChildren
    for node in tree.getChildNodes():
AttributeError: 'Module' object has no attribute 'getChildNodes'
```

I'm using PyFlakes as a submodule in my dotfiles repo so I cannot use `git clone --recursive` as suggested in the [issue 27](https://github.com/kevinw/pyflakes-vim/issues/27) on the plugin's GitHub. My Vim 7.3 compiled with Python support.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix it using this comand:

```
git submodule update --recursive
```

Just need to know how to update submodule :)